# Uploading a file to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, iis-7

in my .net MVC3 web application I am trying to upload an xlsx file to a specific folder under the root directory.
Its working locally.
On my web server (IIS 7) It doesn't work.
Steps I have already taken:
1. I set the Identity of the AppPool to ApplicationPoolIdentity;
2. In IIS manager I added the DefaultAppPool and the specific MyAppPool to the users and gave them both the write permission to the specific folder.

if I try to upload the file while browing from the server itself - it works fine.

can you help me identify the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a quick question, is there a specific reason why you want to write this file to the web folder?

Comment: yes i want to enable users to load data to sql from excel files.

Comment: Is this because the file needs to be downloaded to the browser? There are other options for that that are much safer. I can post an answer like that if you want. Alternatively, we can try and solve the problem itself. Sorry, scratch that, I misunderstood your question. By root, I thought you meant the web root and not the drive root.

Comment: yes. the file needs to be downloaded to the browser so I can take the data. thinking about it, maybe I don't need to write the file. I take the data from the file and i discard it anyway. I just need to implement it without saving the file... I will appriciate if you could share both options: taking the data without from the excel without writing the file to the server and writing the file.

Comment: I think that for what I am trying to do I have to write the file. i use ExcelQueryFactory and it seems to me that for that I have to have a path to the file and thus I need to save it.

Comment: It looks like ExcelQueryFactory unfortunately needs a physical file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14429/discussion-between-graymatter-and-shlo)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I will put something together for the other option.</strike> In the mean time have you tried using impersonation?

Do the following:

Create a user on the server that has access to the folder in question.

Put this in your web.config file:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="ServerName\UserName", password="Password" />
```

Where ServerName is the name of your server, Username is the user you created and  Password is the password in question.

Some more information on impersonation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I have somthing like this:<identity impersonate="true" password="Password" userName="UserName" />. is it the same?

Comment: You should put the domain in before the username "domain\username" if the user is created on a domain or "servername\username" if its on the server itself. It may not be required but it's better to be safe.

Comment: Make sure you recycle your app pool after making these sort of changes.

Comment: Thank you Graymatter! my problem was that I was using the ExcelQueryFactory and I had to install on my server Microsoft Access DataBase Engine. Just after allowing exceptions on remote machine I realized it... I appriciate your help!